# iOS app holds its state for 2 seconds even after killing it

Tags: ios, swift

App has tab bar controller landing page view controller. However even after killing the app and restarting within very short period of time (approximately 2 secs) it holds the previous state on opening for 1 seconds and refreshes. Is it any iOS feature?

Comment: This is normal behavior. App requires time to be "killed" (doing tasks like saving the state, etc.)

Comment: I have not observed this kind of behaviour in any other apps, Tried with photos, google maps,facebook. Once killed it doesnt show the old state.  @Raptor Any work around we can opt for.

Comment: If the app is more complex (in terms of computation and graphics), the delay will be more obvious, such as PokemonGO and many other games. For utility apps like WhatsApp, they tend to have less delay.

Comment: @Raptor, The way it behaves and considering the size of the app I am not much convinced to myself that it could happen. Its not a game app. is this has been raised to apple or discussed anywhere as artifacts.